# I cannot import a Python package despite it being on the right path

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-module, pypi

I wrote a Python package and uploaded it to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/graphab4py/) (note: I have been working on Python 3.11.3 and set Python >=3.11 as a requirement to make sure the package is compatible).

Subsequently, I installed it via `pip` by executing `pip install graphab4py`. However, I could not import it in a Python script (which is not the case with other packages I installed via `pip`.) To be sure, I set up a virtual environment and installed the package there. Within the virtual environment, I started a Python session and tried to import the package, again with no success.

I stumbled upon some suggestions on how to list available packages and I tried the following in Python in my virtual environment:

```
for dist in __import__('pkg_resources').working_set:
    print(dist.project_name.replace('Python', ''))
```

output:

```
setuptools
pip
graphab4py
```

It clearly lists the package there. So I tried `import graphab4py` again, and, once more, I got

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphab4py'
```

So I suspect there might be something wrong with my package? Does anybody have a clue what the issue might be?

**Edit**

I found some hint that there might be some issue with the installation: Where my packages are located, there is a folder `graphab4py-1.0.1.dist-info` but no folder named `graphab4py`. There was no error during the installation, though. The package code can also be viewed on [GitHub](https://github.com/ManuelPopp/graphab4py)

Comment: I think your setup.py didn't find any packages. Add an empty `src/graphab4py/__init__.py` and rebuild your distributions.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks, this is surely one of the issues. I also found that even after adding the ```__init__.py```, the package was not found since it is "hidden" in ```/src```. So I adjusted ```find_packages("./src") in ```setup.py``` (when I run this in Python, it now finds the package) and added ```[tool.setuptools.packages.find]```
```where = ["src"]```
```include = ["*"]```
```namespaces = false``` in ```pyproj.toml```, but still, only the dist-info is installed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @tdelaney and a lot of web pages, I made it work.
First of all, an `__init__.py` file was missing. The other issue was that the package is located within `./src` and it was necessary to point that out. So I added in `setup.py`:

```
setup(
      ...
      package_dir = {"": "src"},
      packages = find_packages("./src"),
      ...
)
```

and in `pyproj.toml`:

```
[tool.setuptools]
package-dir = {"" = "src"}

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
include = ["*"]
namespaces = false
```

of which I believe some must be superfluous, but at least I can now install and import the package. Feel free to point out what changes coule have been done better/more efficiently.